# CodeMirror with Zen Coding not working

Tags: javascript, codemirror, emmet

I'm trying to get Zen Coding working for CodeMirror (for a project already using CodeMirror successfully). Following the [demo](http://zen-coding.ru/codemirror/), I'm initializing the CodeMirror instance like so:

```js
var myCodeMirror = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("editarea"), {
    theme: "blackboard",
    lineNumbers : true,
    syntax: 'html',
    onLoad: function (editor) {
        zen_editor.bind(editor);
    }
});
```

But the Zen Coding feature does not seem to be working at all (hitting tab seem to have no effect), and there are no errors on the JavaScript console. Does anyone have any experience, or can point me to relevant material?

Files are loaded in this order:

```html
<script src="codemirror/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
<script src="codemirror/mode/xml/xml.js"></script>
<script src="codemirror/mode/javascript/javascript.js"></script>
<script src="codemirror/mode/css/css.js"></script>
<script src="codemirror/mode/htmlmixed/htmlmixed.js"></script>
<script src="js/zen_codemirror.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use Emmet (a re-branded Zen Coding project): https://github.com/emmetio/codemirror

Looks like you’re using newer version of CodeMirror which is not supported by Zen Coding plugin.